# Converting Sheet data to a new Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to communicate with Google Sheets to do the following:
We're trying to convert data from one Point of Sale system to a new one. In order to do this, I need to take certain columns of a sheet, manipulate them in various ways, and repopulate another sheet with the resulting data. I need to find products without a SKU number, and assign them a new one, starting at 10110 and incrementing from there.

```html
function sku() {
  // "From" Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("New POS Data");
  
  // "To" Spreadsheet
  // Spreadsheet key: the string at the end of the URL
  var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BH-j4cOW9Ntg6FlPNXmNCUId_pm9BgyAh0cwrwB4z_A");
  var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("Old POS Data");
  var max = sheet.getLastRow();
  // SKU / UPC
  var range = sheetraw.getRange(2,18,max);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  // Assign new sku if no old one
  var skunum=[10110];
  var newData = new Array();
  for (var y = 0; y <= max; y++) {
    if (data[y]==""){
      newData.push(skunum);
      skunum++;
      var skunum=[skunum];
    }
    else {newData.push(data[y]);}
  }
  
  sheet.getRange(2,3,max).setValues(newData);
}
```

This gives me the error "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 30 (line 26, file "SKU")"

If I remove the brackets around newData in the last line, I get "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 27, file "")"

This has been driving me mental, if anyone can offer help, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get a one row or one column vector with `getData()` you will get an `Object[][]`.
when you do:

```
if (data[y]==""){
  newData.push(skunum);
  skunum++;
  var skunum=[skunum];
}
```

You check if `[cellFromColumn] == ""` which will evaluate to false as it's an array.
You then push the new/old sku number to a simple array which, for spreadsheets, is one row of columns.
Instead you want to push into the array a one element array containin the sku number like this:

```
newData.push(skunum);
...
newData.push([data[y]]);
```

This will create an array of rows, each row is an array with one element (one column)

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I do that my, newData variable looks like this:
[[10110], [[5]], [[6]], 10111, 10112, 10113, 10114, 1....
And I get the "Cannot convert array to object" error. I may be wrong, but it appears the problem is that after I first increment skunum, it turns into a number type and not an array. How can I Increment skunum while keeping it an array and not a number? Or am I incorrect about that being the problem?

Comment: You also set `skunum` to `[skunum]`. An array cannot be incremented and you will just keep nesting it deeper.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I swear I tried it that way and it wouldn't work, but it's working now! Much appreciated

Comment: Fantastic! If this helped you can you please accept the answer? Thanks